# Locating a record in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is written in Access. I have this sub. This is meant to go through a recordset and print out individual pages, individually named based on the invoice number:

```
Sub printPdfPages(formName As String, fileName As String)
''print each record into a separate pdf file, named according to invoice number

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim whereCondition As String
    Dim saveName As String

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(fileName)   ''can also pass SQL in as a String
    Do While Not rs.EOF

       saveName = rs!invoiceNumber & ".pdf"
       whereCondition = "[invoiceNumber]=" & rs!invoiceNumber
       '' MsgBox whereCondition


       DoCmd.OpenForm formName, acNormal, , whereCondition
       DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, formName, acFormatPDF, saveName, False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    DoCmd.Close acForm, formName
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now I want to modify it so that it will take in a beginning invoice number and an end invoice number.
Then go to the record of the beginning invoice and print anything between beginning and end.

How can I do that and what method should I use? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, sort your recordset query by invoice number using the order by clause in the SQL string: `ORDER BY invoiceNumber`

Second, you can use the [MoveLast and MoveFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods, just before the loop:

```
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(fileName)

    Do While Not rs.EOF
    ...
```

Aside, refrain from saving forms as documents. Due to Access Reports print setting, margin, and page structure, they are better objects for any document end use including PDF output.

Comment: yeah, I tried to print report as documents but I don't know enough methods in Access VBA to print 1 page of the report at a time. It always print everything in 1 document. That's why I want to know what methods are available to do what I want to do.

Comment: You can filter the report just like you are doing with this form to a particular record. See [OpenReport method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx).

Comment: yeah, that's what I did. It just prints out the whole report. I think because I set up the report source to be the table instead of a record. How can I set up the source from a single record instead of the whole table?

Comment: What did you put as your filter? Condition it to return one record at a time like using a primary id or as in this form example with `invoiceNumber`.

Comment: "InvoiceNumber=" & tableName!invoiceNumber

Comment: Several records may be lumped under a particular `InvoiceNumber`. Consider filtering by primary key or use report grouping that breaks by pages.